# How to add a new entry to route table?

Tags: ethernet, bridge, routing

I have two computers host1 and host2. From host1 I can ping Vitrual Machines with IP addresses like 192.168.122.0/24 fine (there is a bridge for the Virtual Machines). But I cannot do that from host2.

Given that both host1 and host2 are part of eth0 and can ping each other fine, do you think there is a way to ping the IPs in 192.168.122.0/24 from host2? How would you go about it?

I thought about adding something similar to this into the routing table "route add -host 192.168.122.11 gw 172.8.30.150 eth0" but It doesn't work.

Thank you for any hints/ideas on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying that you have two separate computers...one of which is housing VMs.  And you can't ping the far vm inside the other host, your gw needs to be the far host...or you also need a route in the router pointing back at the local host and some SRTs to hairpin traffic.  If you are bridging, sometimes a bit more is required.  To do this, I have previously put eth0 in promisc mode and added it to a bridge group with some tap interfaces.  I then use the tap interfaces inside the vm.  This can get past a lot of routing/switching weirdness and the eth0 interface disregarding traffic destined for the VM in some instances

Comment: SRTs = stupid router tricks...they don't hairpin traffic by design

Comment: Hi aking, thanks for your answer. But i'm not sure I understand what needs to be done? should I add another route entry into the routing table of the VMs? could you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: the VMs shouldn't need routes...i'm trying to get a clearer picture of your layout.  was i correct on the two physical hosts and you can't ping vms on the far host from the other computer?

Comment: paint and OO draw are both free and there are image hosting services if we can't close the gap another way....and what is the host OS(not the guest OS)...linux network stack doesn't process traffic it thinks is destined for itself.  that can be a problem in VMs so the bridge with taps is a recommendation

Comment: if it seems like i am being obtuse or obscure i'm not trying to be...i really want to help on this one(when i got started in virtualization it was for dynamips not pertinent why, but i beat my head into a wall for DAYS b/c no one could help)

Comment: yes you are right. In fact the VMs are running on host1, so that's why I can ping the VMs from it.

Comment: okay and you are using bridged networking, nat, what...bridged is preferable, and the eth0 int in promisc mode is required the way i do it

Comment: i would try something like "route add -host 192.168.122.11 gw IP_OF_HOST2 eth0"...still not sure on your addressing scheme.  the VMs should be on the same network as the physical machine

Comment: thanks aking :) Yes i'm using bridged networking. The route command you gave is the same one I'm using above. I replaced IP_OF_HOST2 by its IP on eth0. But it isn't working : no ping reply. And yes, I'm indeed starting on virtualization and I need help!